# Converter um arquivo .pdf ou .P7s para base64 em C#

Tags: c#, xml, pdf

Quero converter um arquivo .pdf ou .P7s  para base64 em C# o qual deverá ser carregado no XML. Como posso fazer?

EX:

```
<conteudoArquivoP7S>
    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
</conteudoArquivoP7S>
```

Answer (score 3):

Um código genérico de codificação de arquivo em base64 deve resolver:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("C:\\Caminho\\Do\\Arquivo.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
{
    byte[] bytesArquivo = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(bytesArquivo, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    string stringEmBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesArquivo); 
}
```

Para confeccionar o XML, [uso a classe `XmlOutput` do Mark Rasmussen](http://improve.dk/xmldocument-fluent-interface/). [Fiz um pacote NuGet para ela](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XmlOutput/). O uso é assim:

```
var xo = new XmlOutput()
    .XmlDeclaration()
    .Node("conteudoArquivoP7S").InnerText(stringEmBase64);
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Cigano. Deu certo!!

Comment: @JoeliasAndrade A resposta atendeu ao seu problema? [Veja aqui este link sobre como usar o site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Obrigado!